# How to create a Box with component 'form' that allows onSubmit Event?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code that definitely worked in MUI (Material-UI). However, when I isolate the style into its separate styled component using the styled() function, I get a TypeScript error.

> Type '(event: FormEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler'.
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'FormEvent' is not assignable to type 'FormEvent'.
> Type 'HTMLDivElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLFormElement': acceptCharset, action, autocomplete, elements, and 15 more.ts(2322)

```js
  
  // Mui styled component 
  export const StyledEntryBox = styled(Box)<BoxProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  // custom style 
  }));
  
  // Handler
  const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {}
  
  // My component (box/form)
  <StyledEntryBox component='form' boxShadow={3} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  </StyledEntryBox>
```

sure the solution is to nest the from beneth the box but it is kind weires sice i cam state the box component as from yet what is the right type for the onsubmit fn ?

Comment: why dont just use `const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent): void => {}`?

Comment: @VladVladov thanks worked please write an answer explaining what I was doing wrong.